# Ошибка: "значение типа "const char*" нельзя присвоить сущности типа char"

Tags: c++, char

```
  #include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int num_1,num_2,num_3,in;
char fun,ch;
bool more;
int main()
{
    more = true;
        cout << "Example: x <enter> + <enter> y" << endl;
        do {
            cin >> num_1 >> fun >> num_2;
            if (fun = "+") { in = 1; }
            if (fun = "-") { in = 2; }
            if (fun = "*") { in = 3; }
            if (fun = "/") { in = 4; }
            switch (in)
        {
            case 1: {num_3 = num_1 + num_2;}
            case 2: {num_3 = num_1 - num_2;}
            case 3: {num_3 = num_1 * num_2;}
            case 4: {num_3 = num_1 / num_2;}
            default: {cout << endl << "I'm sorry, you enter something wrong";}
        }
            cout << "Result: " << num_3 << " \n";
        cout << "More? (y/n) ";
        cin >> more;
        if (more = "n") more = false;
    } while (more = true);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Выходит ошибка **"значение типа "const char*" нельзя присвоить сущности типа char"** в фрагменте:

```
if (fun = "+") { in = 1; }
if (fun = "-") { in = 2; }
if (fun = "*") { in = 3; }
if (fun = "/") { in = 4; }
```

Уже несколько дней не могу найти решение.

Comment: пиши не `"+"`, а `'+'`

Comment: ffk, благодарю!

Comment: Следующим вопросом явно будет, почему все равно не работает, а ответом - потому что в `if` не сравнение, а присваивание...

Comment: Следующим вопросом будет: Выводятся неверные вычисления (пример 12+12=1). Забавно, но так так и есть...

Comment: А я вам ответ написал **до** вашего вопроса. Перечитайте внимательно!

Comment: Это конечно уж слишком глупо, но в фрагменте `if (more = "n") more = false;` происходит зацикливание в любом случае.

Comment: Естественно. Вы *булевой* переменной присваиваете ненулевой указатель... Вобщем, смотрите мой ответ, потому как по одной ошибке исправлять - до вечера...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Вот](https://ideone.com/BrpGhO), после исправления ошибок...

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int num_1,num_2,num_3;
    char fun;
    cout << "Example: x@y: " << endl;
    do {
        cin >> num_1 >> fun >> num_2;
        switch (fun)
        {
        case '+': {num_3 = num_1 + num_2;} break;
        case '-': {num_3 = num_1 - num_2;} break;
        case '*': {num_3 = num_1 * num_2;} break;
        case '/': {num_3 = num_1 / num_2;} break;
        default: {cout << endl << "I'm sorry, you enter something wrong";}
        }
        cout << "Result: " << num_3 << " \n";
        cout << "More? (y/n) ";
        cin >> fun;
        if (fun == 'n') break;
    } while(true);
    return 0;
}
```

И не надо постоянно жать на Enter - вводите сразу типа `12+12`...